# How to pass ChangeNotifier in Navigator?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, provider

I have a class which extends to ChangeNotifier. My home page listens to one of the bool variable of this class and updates its UI. From My home page, I have a Navigator.push (screen1) and from this, I have another Navigator (screen2). From screen2 I want to change the value of that bool variable of the class. So how can I pass my Provider so that I make the change from screen 2, which is stacked in Navigator and I could listen in my HomePage?

My ChangeNotifierProvider is added above HomePage.

edit: Solution that worked for me was adding the ChangeNotifierProvider above MaterialApp in MultiProvider

but is this an efficient way? as I have placed ChangeNotifierProvider so above in my tree , where its not been used.

Answer (score 0):

The common practice (see [provider example](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example)) is to have a `Provider` at the top of the widget tree. So yes, it is efficient, no worries.